# Extract and use specific data from a text file in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

Ok, I managed to extract the data I wanted from a file, but there is a problem when trying to calculate those extracted numbers (perform addition).

The numbers are stored here 
       cout << stod( line.substr( position + 1 ) ) << endl;

I tried like this

```
   sum = stod( line.substr( position + 1 ) );
   sum = sum * 5.0;
   cout << sum << endl;
```

Since this is in a while loop, my program performes the calculation again adn again, so I get each price multiplied by five, but I only want to do addition like: sum+sum+sum+sum+sum.
I even wrote that and I of course get the same thing.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <fstream>
   #include <cstdlib>
   using namespace std;

   void KeyWord(ifstream &FileSearch)
   {
string line;
string letters[5];
long sum[6];
ifstream readSearch;

cout<< "Enter a barcode of a product: \n";
cin >> letters[0];
cin >> letters[1];
cin >> letters[2];
cin >> letters[3];
cin >> letters[4];
readSearch.open("Products.txt");
if(readSearch.is_open())
{
    while (getline(readSearch, line))
    {
        while (line.find(letters[0])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[1])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[2])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[3])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[4])!=string::npos)
        {
            cout << line << "\n";
            auto position = line.find( "$" );
            if( position <= line.size() )
            {
                cout << stod( line.substr( position + 1 ) ) << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
   }

   int main()
   {
ifstream file("Products.txt");
KeyWord(file);
return 0;
   }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not useful to anyone, but those with this very same assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some brute force for you to play with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


double getPrice( string inputLine )
{
    auto position = inputLine.find( "$" );

    if( position <= inputLine.size() )
    {
        return stod( inputLine.substr( position + 1 ) );
    }

    return 0;
}

string getBarCode( string inputLine )
{
    auto position = inputLine.find( '$' );

    position -= 1;

    string barCode;

    while( isspace( inputLine[ position ] ) )
    {
        --position;
    }

    while( ! isspace( inputLine[ position ] ) )
    {
        barCode.insert( barCode.begin(), inputLine[ position-- ] );
    }

    return barCode;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    cout << "Enter barcode: " << endl;

    string barcodeInput;
    getline( cin, barcodeInput );

    ifstream inputFile( "Products.txt" );

    if( inputFile.is_open() )
    {
        string inputLine;

        while( getline( inputFile, inputLine) )
        {
            auto price = getPrice( inputLine );

            if( price != 0 )
            {
                if( getBarCode( inputLine ) == barcodeInput )
                {
                    cout << "Price: " << price << endl;

                    inputFile.close();

                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "No matching barcode." << endl;

        inputFile.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
while (getline(readSearch, line))
{
    int pos = line.find_last_of('$');
    double num = stod(line.substr(pos + 1, line.size() - pos - 1));
    //cout << num << endl;
}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: This is what I got when put this code

       Enter a barcode of a product: 
       Backpack
      Bag
       Toy
       Ball
       Pen
       1.5
       1
       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type        std::invalid_argument: stod: no conversion
(lldb)

Comment: The input line doesn't have any pure numeric number. So, you should extract it programmatically. And, according to input line, price should be started with $ sign. If there is no $ sign in price, you won't get the expected result.