# How to extract floating point numbers from a string?

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I need to read a line of text which contains letters, integers and floating point numbers and than calculate those floating point numbers. What I have done so far is below

```
           while (getline(readSearch, line))
    {
        while (line.find(letters[0])!=string::npos ||   line.find(letters[1])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[2])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[3])!=string::npos || line.find(letters[4])!=string::npos)
        {
            cout << line << "\n";
            break;
        }
```

Here is the file that I am reading from

```
   Chips 01c $0.50
   Juice  02j  $1.5
   Chocolate 03c $1.00
   Pen 04p 0.20
   Backpack 05b $30.00
   Bag 06b $35.25
   Ball 07b $10.50
   Toy 08t $15.22
   Wi-Fi Router 09wr $40.00
   Generic HDMI cable 010hc $4.00
```

Since this file contains three different types of data it is really hard for me to figure out how to calculate only those floating point numbers which are representing prices.
I need to somehow input them to a variable and than perform calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure what "calculate those floating point numbers" means.  What are you calculating?  If you want to know how to parse the line to find the portion following the '$' character, and then how to interpret that string as a float, you'll want to look at std::string::find, std::string::substr, and std::stringstream

Comment: You might be interested in the [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) standard function. Will make your big condition in the `if` statement a little shorter and readable. Something I forgot to mention [in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969068/extract-and-use-specific-data-from-a-text-file-in-c). Which brings me to another thing: Don't repost basically the same question twice. Refine the first one until you get an answer you can work with. If you're unlucky you won't get an acceptable answer at all, that's how it works.

Comment: As I am beginner, could you please write that code here? I used the code above to get the numbers following the $ sign but I am getting some weird errors. I can get two or three lines printed correctly and than some error message appears.
Also I am sorry for reposting the same question, I thought that I would raise the chance to get answer faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since this file contains three different types

They you should define three different types. Define the input operator for each type. Then define a type for the row of data and you can just read in the three different types.

#### DataLine

```
struct DataLine
{
    std::string name;   // Wi-Fi Router
    DataBlob    blob;   // 010hc 
    Price       price;  // $40.00

    void swap(DataLine& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(name,   other.name);
        swap(blob,   other.blob);
        swap(price,  other.price);
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, DataLine& data)
    {
        std::string line;
        if (std::getline(s, line))
        {
            // The name takes up all but the last two space separated words.
            // So find that point first.
            std::size_t  first  = line.find_last_of(" \t");
            std::size_t  second = (first == 0)
                                      ? std::string::npos 
                                      : line.find_last_of(" \t", first-1);
            std::stringstream lineStream(line);
            DataLine  tmp;
            if (lineStream >> ItemNameReader(tmp.name, second - 1) >> tmp.blob >> tmp.price) {
               // All three items were read correctly
               // So update the object with the new state.
               data.swap(tmp);
            }
            else {
               // One of the read operations failed.
               // So set the state of the stream to bad
               // The user can then handle this situation.
               s. setstate(std::ios::badbit);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
};
```

#### ItemNameReader

```
struct ItemNameReader
{
    std::string&  name;
    std::size_t   size;
    ItemNameReader(std::string& name, std::size_t size)
        : name(name)
        , size(size)
    {}
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, ItemNameReader const& data)
    {
        data.name.resize(data.size);
        s.read(data.name.data(), data.size);
        return s;
    }   
};
```

#### DataBlob

```
class DataBlob
{
    std::string   blob;
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, DataBlob& data)
    {
        return s >> data.blob;
    }
};
```

#### Price

```
class Price
{
    char  units;
    float value;  // Though you may want to consider monetary
                  // units as integer values to avoid any rounding
                  // issues associated with floating point. 
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& s, Price& data)
    {
        return s >> data.units >> data.value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) the appropriate delimiter to locate the [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) you're interested in, then use a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) to convert to float/double.  There are equivalent std objects for wstring operations.